# confusing ltrim charlist behavior

Tags: php

Example:

```
$hello  = "Hello World";
$trimmed = ltrim($hello, "Hdle");
var_dump($trimmed);
```

Which results to:

```
string(7) "o World"
```

How come it did not remove `d` and `l` at the second word?

Answer (score 5):

Because you are using [*`ltrim`*](http://php.net/ltrim), which *trims left*. Only [`trim`](http://php.net/trim) trims on both sides.

Comment: what? I don't understand.

Comment: Really?! `ltrim` removes characters from the left of the input. `rtrim` from the right. `trim` from both sides. RTFM?

Comment: perhaps he wants str_replace()

Comment: @Dagon Perhaps he wants a pony, who knows? ;)

Comment: @PineappleUndertheSea well.. 'don't understand' - that's something new :p It's a plain text. Yes. Black letters on a white background. And - in english. yes:p

Comment: would he keep the pony under the sea you think ?

Comment: @Dagon Only if it's a sea horse, otherwise... poor thing.